# Semiconductors and energy bands

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

The valence and conduction band of a semi-conductor are often drawn as here [click.](http://users-phys.au.dk/philip/pictures/solid_semiconductors/britney.gif)

This plot has essentially two features and I would like to understand them.

The peak and the valley of the two bands coincide, in what sense is this a characteristic feature for a semiconductor. I mean, I could have that they don't agree at all, would this necessarily mean that my material is not a semiconductor. I don't think so, as this should mostly depend on the energy gap. So why is this important in these drawings?

Both bands are drawn as parabolas ( with opposite curvatures), where does this come from?

Answer (score 3):

If the valence band maximum and the conduction band minimum are on the same position in k-space, this means that you have a direct gap semiconductor (GaAs, InAs, ...). If the CB minimum is at a finite k-value, it would be an indirect gap semiconductor (like Si, Ge, AlAs, ...)

The bands appear as parabolas due to the dispersion of a quasi-free electron/hole 
$$ E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2 m^{\ast}} $$

Real bandstructures are not perfectly parabolic, but it serves as a good approximation around k = 0.

Comment: And the opposite curvature is explained by negative effective mass for electron holes - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)

Comment: What does 'k' represent on the graph?